# C++, VS13 GetModuleFileNameA doesn't return special characters

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get a path of the current .exe file. I am using function:

```
std::string getexepath()
{
    char result[MAX_PATH];
    return std::string(result, GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, result, MAX_PATH));
}
```

The folder with the .exe file is (Russian):

```
C:\Users\monav\Desktop\русский\
```

Unfortunately, the function returns:

```
C:\Users\monav\Desktop\??????\
```

So instead I tried to use:

```
wchar_t result[MAX_PATH];
wstring wtf = std::wstring(result, GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, result, MAX_PATH));
```

It gives the right output (when I test it in MessageBoxW), however I have to use string instead of wstring (my code is very long, and the "exepath" is used in many places). So I tried to convert wstring to string using:

```
string ws2s(const std::wstring& wstr)
{
    typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> convert_type;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;
    std::string converted_str = converter.to_bytes(string_to_convert);
    return converted_str;
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't give the right output. It looks like:
[image: none]

I tried some other wstring to string conversion methods, unfortunately with no success.
My question is: Is it possible to convert this wstring with special characters to string? If yes, then how? My program is using boost libraries.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Unless your system locale uses a Russian character set, then there's no way to make this work except by using Unicode strings. The "ANSI" versions of the Windows API function use the ANSI character set, and the ANSI character set is never UTF-8. It's always a region specific character set like CP-1252 (Latin-1) for US/English systems, or CP-1251 (Cyrillic) for Russian systems. You're either going to have accept that your program doesn't work correctly with Russian file names on non-Russian PC or fix your program so that it uses Unicode so it doesn't matter.

Comment: For what it is worth, the `ws2s()` output *IS* correct.  It is returning the output as a proper UTF-8 encoded `std::string`. The problem is that you are displaying the UTF-8 string as-is in a Win32 message box, which does not support UTF-8. You are seeing the UTF-8 octets being interpreted in the system's default locale, which is likely Latin-1 (codepage 1252 or 28591). If you retrieve the filename as a UTF-8 string, make sure your code can actually handle UTF-8 strings. Otherwise, switch everything to `std::wstring` so you can use Unicode (UTF-16) strings.

Comment: They're not "special characters", they're just "characters".

Comment: Thanks for your replies and tips. I decided to change required strings to wstrings. I had to fix around 500 lines of the code, but hopefuly it was worth.
@Ross, I tried GetModuleFileNameA on a Win10 Virtual Machine with Russian language pack installed, but it was returning those question marks... I was really confused.
At least now I know to use wchar_t whenever it's possible, in my future codes :)

Comment: The language packs don't change the ANSI character set as far as I know. They wouldn't need to since Windows itself uses Unicode for everything. Assuming it hasn't changed in Windows 10, in order to change the ANSI character set you need to go to the control panel, find whatever they're calling the locale settings control panel app now (eg. "Region and Language"), select the Administrative tab, and change the "Language for non-Unicode Programs" setting.